# How to get date if we have fiscal week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have stored fiscal week in my table as `Nvarchar(Max)`

```
CREATE TABLE sample(
                    id int
                    ,FiscalWeekName NvarChar(MAX)
                   );

INSERT INTO sample VALUES(1,'FY15-W1');
```

No, I want to convert this `fiscalweekname` into the first day of that week

For example query should return

```
01-01-2014
```

Comment: How did `'FY15-W1` become`'01-01-2014'`?

Comment: The question doesnt make sense. What would `'FY15-W3'` represent?

Comment: @Felix financial year number is always one greater than actual year

Comment: @Alpha:- How is `'FY15-W3'` representing `13-01-2014`?

Comment: @Apha : - 'FY15-W1' : 01-01-2014,  'FY15-W2' : 06-01-2014,  'FY15-W3' : 12-01-2014,  'FY15-W4' : 20-01-2014, and so on

Comment: @sanjay 'FY15-W1' : 01-01-2014, 'FY15-W2' : 06-01-2014, 'FY15-W3' : 13-01-2014, 'FY15-W4' : 20-01-2014, and so on

Comment: @rahul Check the calendar of 2014,you will get it

Comment: Sometimes the first "fiscal week" has to have four days. Is that your rule here?

Comment: @shawnt00 No this is not rule. If you see calendar the first week of 2014 has only 4 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even know how you define fiscal weeks but here's a stab:

```
dateadd(
    week,
    cast(substring(FiscalWeekName, 7, 2) as int) - 1,
    dateadd(year, -1, cast('20' + substring(FiscalWeekName, 3, 2) + '0101' as date))
)
```

A numeric year by itself will cast to January 1 but it's probably safer not to rely on that so I added the `'0101'`.

EDIT: After your clarification I'm trying to adjust the day of week to slide back to Monday (and I'm assuming that's what your `DATEFIRST` setting is as well.) This seems messy so maybe there's a cleaner way.

```
dateadd(
    day,
    (cast(substring(FiscalWeekName, 7, 2) as int) - 1) * 7
      - case
            when cast(substring(FiscalWeekName, 7, 2) as int) > 1
            then
                datepart(
                    dw,
                    dateadd(
                        year,
                        -1,
                        cast('20' + substring(FiscalWeekName, 3, 2) + '0101' as date)
                    )
                )
            else 0
        end,
    dateadd(year, -1, cast('20' + substring(FiscalWeekName, 3, 2) + '0101' as date))
)
```

Comment: I think it should be `substring(FiscalWeekName, 3, 2)`.

Comment: Yup, and the 'W' is in a fixed position so no need for the `charindex`.

Comment: above query gives error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: error because of dateadd(yy, -1, cast('20'+substring(@FiscalWeekName, 2, 2)+'0101' as date) and this should be dateadd(yy, -1, cast('20'+substring(@FiscalWeekName, 3, 2)+'0101' as date)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, correction from @shawnt00

```
declare @FiscalWeekName as NvarChar(MAX)
set @FiscalWeekName = 'FY15-W2'

SELECT cast(substring(@FiscalWeekName, charindex('W', @FiscalWeekName) + 1, 2) as int),  dateadd(
    wk,
    cast(substring(@FiscalWeekName, charindex('W', @FiscalWeekName) + 1, 2) as int) 
    ,dateadd(yy, -1, cast('20'+substring(@FiscalWeekName, 3, 2)+'0101' as date))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution will give you the first day/date of week as per Fiscal+Week,

```
declare @FiscalWeekName as NvarChar(MAX)
set @FiscalWeekName = 'FY15-W5'

DECLARE @FiscalYear as datetime
set @FiscalYear = dateadd(
    WEEK,
    cast(substring(@FiscalWeekName, charindex('W', @FiscalWeekName) + 1, 2) as int) -1
    ,dateadd(yy, -1, cast('20'+substring(@FiscalWeekName, 3, 2)+'0101 01:01:01.1111111' as date))
)

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @FiscalYear)-1), @FiscalYear) as FiscalYear
```